# VBA - Suggest an idea to increase the Serial Number if Num of Sheet increases

Tags: vba

I am working on an excel workbook which has 20 sheets (named LAP1 to LAP20) and finally one summary sheet named "Summary".

In the summary sheet, there is one column for LAP no, currently it is filled with 1 to 20.

How can I make excel automatically update the column like 21,22,23,... when I create the sheets LAP21,LAP22,...?

Comment: improve formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

`Workbook_NewSheet` will be auto triggered when a new worksheet added.

On Workbook Module paste the below code. - change range `A1` according to your need.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim x As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        x = x + 1
    Next
    Sheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value = x - 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create event in ThisWorkbook-> NewSheet

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

'your code update sheets list in summary sheet

End Sub
```

and if names of sheets can be random event on SheetChange

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'update sheets names in summary sheet

End Sub
```